# GEE: Divide satellite imagery pixels into smaller sized pixels, without projection being changed

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to divide the moderate resolution satellite imagery into smaller pixels. To clarify this, I took a Landsat 30x30m image. For further analysis, I first want to split all pixels into 3x3m pixels, exactly corresponding with the original pixels. The method ee.Image.reproject() seems to come closest, although the pixels are reprojected into a slight different projection and therefore the pixels do not match with the original Landsat pixels. How can I Create an image where all new smaller pixels exactly match the original image?

Here a piece of simplified code which shows the mismatch (zoomed in to the corner of the image, where the mismatch is most clearly seen):

**The mismatch removes when '.clip' is done at the end, where the image is added to the map**

```js
// Extent for the images to clip
var Haurvig = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([8.1247, 55.927, 8.1625, 55.907]);

// Load an LS8 image with least clouds
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                     .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-01')
                     .filterBounds(Haurvig)
                     .sort('CLOUD_COVER').first();
// rename the band names and clip the image
var image =  image.select(['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B10','pixel_qa'])
          .rename(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2','tir','qa'])
          .clip(Haurvig);    

// Reproject the image to 3x3 m
var reprojected = image.reproject(image.projection().crs(), null, 3);

// add to the map
var trueColor = {bands: ['red','green','blue'], min: 300, max: 3800};
Map.addLayer(reprojected, trueColor, 'Reprojected image');
Map.addLayer(image, trueColor, 'Original image');
Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point([8.162408851233522,55.907053640896]), 20);
```

Comment: Although what you are asking for is possible, it is often not the most efficient way to use Earth Engine. Stepping back a level, what are you planning on doing with the image with 3x3m pixels (i.e. what is your overall goal)? This may help others suggest a good solution.

Comment: I didn't want to add that in my question, as that could start a discussion. However, what I would like to approach is the method described in this article (https://doi.org/10.1080/01431160500213292; super resolution mapping). Using first Linear spectral unmixing on a per-pixel basis, I would like to classify water, sand and vegetation on a sub-pixel scale, maintaining the original information on the pixels itself. The ultimate goal is to get a polygons/lines which shed purely water from the beach and marks the abrupt change from sand overblown dunes to vegetated dunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'd like to start off this answer by qualifying it to say that the approach described is useful for *understanding how projections work*, but it is rarely the best approach for large-scale image analysis workflows. The use of `ee.Image.reproject()` short-circuit's Earth Engine's default behavior of reprojecting as needed and using image pyramids to efficiently query data. Make sure to read the Earth Engine docs on [Projections](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections) and [Resampling](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/resample) to understand how `ee.Image.reproject()` works before using it.**

That being said, here is a way to create a small sample image with pixels that are aligned with the original image.

```js
//  Define a small Region of Interest (ROI) used to clip results.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point(8.3431, 55.8825).buffer(60);

// Load an LS8 image with least clouds.
var image_1 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                     .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-01')
                     .filterBounds(roi)
                     .sort('CLOUD_COVER').first();
```

Get the projection information from the image, and scale it to create a new projection that has 10 times as many pixels in each dimension.

```js
// Resample and reproject the image to the new projection.
var projection_1 = image_1.projection();
var projection_2 = projection_1.scale(1/10, 1/10);
var image_2 = image_1.resample('bicubic').reproject(projection_2);
```

Note that the `.resample()` method is used to make it easier to compare the original and reprojected pixels. Remove it if you want to use the default 'nearest neighbor' resampling method.

```js
// Print out the projection information, for easy inspection.
print('projection_1', projection_1);
print('projection_2', projection_2);
```

Compare the two projections using a split map view.

```js
// Display the various images as map layers on a split map. 
var TRUE_COLOR_VIS = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 300, max: 600};
var leftMap = ui.Map();
var rightMap = ui.Map();
leftMap.addLayer(image_1.clip(roi), TRUE_COLOR_VIS, 'image_1 (original image)');
rightMap.addLayer(image_2.clip(roi), TRUE_COLOR_VIS, 'image_2 (reprojected to 3m postings)');

// Create a SplitPanel to hold the adjacent, linked maps.
var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel({
  firstPanel: leftMap,
  secondPanel: rightMap,
  wipe: true
});
var linker = ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap]);

// Set the SplitPanel as the only thing in the UI root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([splitPanel]);
leftMap.centerObject(roi);
```

Here is an interactive app for comparing the projections: https://tylere.users.earthengine.app/view/gis-stackexchange-299589

[image]

Source code is here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e7f2fa092999faec3209d07dfd41d5dd#

Note in the original code, the "mismatch" of pixels along the edge was caused by the relative placement of the `.clip()` method, which occurred before the `.reproject()` method. In general, it is a good practice to only use `.clip()` at the end of your analysis (i.e. when displaying results on the map).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only thing missing in my code was thus that I needed to clip in the end of my analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce pixel size with **gdalwarp** command outside of **google-earth-engine** and, afterward, upload there modified raster. Following qgis python code (pyqgis) works well.

```py
import os

raster = iface.activeLayer()
provider = raster.dataProvider()

crs = raster.crs().authid()

input_raster_path = provider.dataSourceUri()

output_raster_path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/NDVI/b3.ND_clip_3_3_res.tif'

root, filename = os.path.split(output_raster_path)

cmd = "gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs " + crs + " -tr " + str(xsize) + " " + str(ysize) + " -s_srs " + crs + " " + \
      input_raster_path + " " + output_raster_path

os.system(cmd)

changed = QgsRasterLayer(output_raster_path,
                         filename)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(changed)
```

I tried it out with raster (30x30 m) of following image:

[image]

Resulting raster has expected resolution (3x3 m) and it is perfectly aligned with original raster.

Comment: Although I am sure it would work fine, the purpose of my research is to develop a systematic way to work this out inside the GEE. Unfortunately, this is not the solution for me.
If there isn't any proper way to do it inside the GEE, I will need to find another approach to coop with the sub-pixel classification of the LS imagery.